# Does rdp'ing into the console session close any applications you launched during a physical log in previously?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

If I launch an application while physically being at the server and then some time later decide to remote into the same server's console session ( /admin flag) and then log out, will that log out close the application that I launched while physically being at the server?  This is usually something that I could test myself but in this scenario gaining physical access to the server is a rare opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, logging out will close all the applications, same as logging out from the console does (by going Start > Log Out)

If you just close the RDP window (by clicking the `x`) that's the same as just walking away from the console - everything will continue to run.